# Take param in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need take params in bash, I can take the param `h`,`c`,`p`,`s`,`a` but i cant take the param `b`.

Why can't I take it? This is my script:

```
if [ ! -z $1 ]; then
    HOSTNAME=""
    CLIENT=""
    SUBSCRIPTIONS_GROUPS=""
    PROVIDER=""
    SERVER=""
    while getopts ":h:c:p:s:a:b" opt; do
            case $opt in 
                    h)  HOSTNAME=${OPTARG}
                            ;;
                    c)  CLIENT=${OPTARG}
                            ;;
                    p)      PROVIDER=${OPTARG}
                            ;;
                    s)  SUBSCRIPTIONS_GROUPS=${OPTARG}
                            ;;
                    a)  ALWAYS_ON="on"
                            ;;
                    b)  SERVER=${OPTARG}
                            ;;
                    ?)  ;;
            esac
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two flaws in your implementation:

- First character is colon
- After `b` there is no colon

Your getops string should look like this:

```
while getopts "h:c:p:s:ab:" opt; do
...
```

> When you want getopts to expect an argument for an option, just place a : (colon) **after** the proper option flag

and

> If the very first character of the option-string is a : (colon), which
>   would normally be nonsense because there's no option letter preceding
>   it, getopts switches to "silent error reporting mode". In productive
>   scripts, this is usually what you want because it allows you to handle
>   errors yourself without being disturbed by annoying messages.

Extracts from http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing the ':' after your parameter 'b'. Also 'a' looks like a boolean flag, so no ':' in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual:

> If a character is followed by a colon, the  option is  expected  to
>   have an argument, which should be supplied as a  separate  argument.

So `b` needs to be followed by a colon.